# How to reduce noise from air conditioner condenser?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have 2 identical ac units outside. One is very quiet but the other has a buzzing noise. Is there any way to fix this?

Video of buzzing: https://youtube.com/shorts/Y-nho8KLE8I?feature=share

Comment: Often such noises come from loose metal making noise when it vibrates, or rotating items like fans which are slightly out of balance or have bearing issues. I'd make sure all the metal parts are properly secured - no screws not fully seated, and try to inspect the fan more closely.

Comment: The noise frequency would correspond to th \e compressor, not the fan